# Zend Studio 9 - Code folding

Tags: zend-studio, code-folding

Is there any trick to collapse one portion of code in Zend Studio 9?
I can collapse functions and/or classes, but there is no support for "if statements" folding nor selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a way to do it with Zend Studio 9. I continue to use Komodo IDE instead.